# Public_html root not getting index file showing 404

Tags: php, server, hosting, remote-server

I have a remote server, Where i have Cpanel access and also i have ssh access, i have one file `index.php` in `public_html`.

Whenever i access `example.com` the url changes to `example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` and it shows some random message.

Why domain is not picking `index.php` file ?

Comment: What happens if you try to access `example.com/index.php` ?

Comment: Can you provide a vhost configuration?

Comment: @Manngo it shows 404.

Comment: Is the cgi-sys directory also inside your `public_html` directory? What else is there?

Comment: Also, is there something like `.htaccess` inside your `public_html` directory?

Comment: I think the issue with the DNS point, your domain is not pointed yet on the server which you have updated the file.

Comment: @Manngo The `public_html` have only file `index.php`.

Comment: @Manngo There is no .htaccess file under `public_html`.

Comment: Here is the situation: the web server will have been set up to treat a particular directory as the web root. Naturally, you would expect this to be you `public_html` directory. It doesn’t look as if this is the case. Have you checked this with your host?

Comment: @Comrade Sorry, I meant with your hosting provider. They will have to fill in the gaps.